# Install without cd or usb

Tags: system-installation, hard-drive

I want to install Ubuntu on a laptop that has no cd/dvd drive, and I don't have a usb flashdrive.

I do have an external HDD with 3TB (there no way to format this, as it is my media collection!) and a couple 320 and/or 500 gig internal HD´s lying around.

I was hoping I could do the following:

- Create virtual flash drive on HD. Then boot the ISO from that, plus installing OS on another partition on that HD.

or

- Install OS  on HD using my pc (with zorin os) then switch it to laptop. (although my pc  is x64, and laptop x86)

Are either of the 2 options even possible?

Or does anyone know a method to solve my problem, without buying a USB (flash) drive?

Thank You very much for your time, (and hopefully help) in advance!

Comment: Yes. You can create a partition, put the ISO(!) (so that 1 file) onto it and point your BIOS to boot from it. Here is a list of methods: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation

Comment: TY Rinzwind, i will check/try that out!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can write the installer image to a hd and boot from it.  If you edit the kernel command line options on the boot menu and add `toram` then it will load entirely into ram and leave the disk unmounted so you can reformat and install the system there.

Assuming `/dev/sdb` is the drive you want to use ( wipe out ):

```
sudo dd if=ubuntu.iso of=/dev/sdb
```

Comment: So u mean in like grub, enter new command line, only typ *toram* ? And sudo dd if...../sdb, just in terminal when running the live cd in RAM right?

Comment: @DrugCrazedRebel, unless you have an EFI system, the livecd boots with syslinux rather than grub, and iirc, it was F6 to edit the kernel command line from the syslinux menu.  Just add the world "toram".  And no, you don't run dd after having booted the livecd in ram, you do that on another pc to MAKE the "livecd" in the HD so you can transfer it back to the machine with no cdrom.